# Use .htaccess to handle folder & its sub folders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I got this working now: `/en/blog/2017/03/13/website-coming-soon` leads to en/blog/blog4.php and so on.

I also want to make `/en/blog` point to /en/blog.php but using `#RewriteRule en/blog/ en/blog.php` messes up the blog posts. I think I should add a condition but can't find the correct syntax online.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/website-coming-soon en/blog/blog4.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/website-for-free en/blog/blog3.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/that-startup-feeling en/blog/blog2.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/how-it-all-started en/blog/blog1.php
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: This looks very chaotic. Please take the time to work through a few examples to actually _understand_ what you are doing. The current code indicates that this currently is _not_ the case.

Comment: About your specific question: your issue most likely is an endless rewrite loop. You need to take care to rewrite only if you have not already done so.

Comment: "messes up the blog posts" - What do you mean exactly? Is the CSS or JS (for example) just not loaded? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, the blog post don't get loaded anymore, instead I see the main blog file.

Comment: Yes, @arkascha I think it's an infinite loop and therefore I have to make sure the rule to rewrite the /blog directory only is executed on the folder and not on the blogs in the folder.

Comment: If the page loads then it is _not_ an infinite loop, you would get an error otherwise.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Got those a while back when I tried something. So, you don't know the solution to the problem? I btw don't agree on your statement that those lines of code are chaotic. They do what they have to do and I understand how they work (I have a lot more other stuff as well in the file). Just need to get the right syntax for only making a rule for the folder that doesn't interfere with the rules for the blog posts themselves.